# How to make a window visible="false" when window mode="modal"

Tags: java, mvvm, zk, zul

```
<window title="My First Window" border="normal" width="200px" visible="false" mode="modal">
Hello, World!
</window>
```

When running this example i expect that there is no popUp window shown as visible="false" ....

But i do get a popUp ... what am i missing ?

When i remove `mode="modal"` it runs fine. So how do we control visible property on window with mode = "model"

[Zk fiddle example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3i68msb/3)

---

Why i want to do the above described;
I am following the `mvvm` model so when something happens in app i want to show a popup by just making the popup window visible that is why i want to create a `modal` window that is immediately dismissed and show it later

Comment: just create a boolean variable in viewmodel and bind into your zul page .for example :

Comment: visible="@bind(vm.booleanVariable)"

Answer (score 1):

Gut feeling is that what you're asking doesn't make sense. A modal window must have focus and must be dismissed before you can move on. So if it's there, how can it not be visible?

Comment: The Window should not be visible as visible="false"

Comment: @user2410148 I understand that, I'm just not sure that stating a window is both not modal and not visible makes sense. If it is not visible, how can it be modal? This may be why it doesn't work. What you're asking for may not fundamentally be valid.

Comment: on zk doc http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Containers/Window#Modal_and_Highlighted  They have written that "To dismiss a modal window, you could make it invisible (Window.setVisible(boolean))"

Comment: Marking an existing (and therefore previously visible) modal window sounds quite different to creating a modal window that is initially invisible. and following the behaviour you cite, I'd then ask why do you want to create a modal window that is immediately dismissed? What is its purpose?

Comment: i am following the mvvm model so when something happens in app i want to show a popup by just making the popup window visible that is why i want to create a modal window that is immediately dismissed and show it later

Comment: @user2410148 Ok. Then I think you might want to rephrase the question in order to describe that more clearly. State your aim, then describe that you've tried to do it by making an invisible modal and that doesn't appear to work. You may find the answer is quite different to the one you're looking for at the moment...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41349/discussion-between-user2410148-and-rob-baillie)

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than showing a Modal Window I will suggest use Notification

```
Clients.showNotification(msg); // display a global notification box
Clients.showNotification(msg, component); // display a notification box pointing to a component
```

And in your code use code like this and see what will happen

```
<window title="My First Window" border="normal" width="200px"  mode="modal" visible="false">
Hello, World!
</window>
```

Comment: is'nt this against mvvm

Comment: you are telling me to pass component in showNotification.. so to do that i need to create a graphic component in java and also keep track of its ref which according to me is against mvvm

Comment: You can use Clients.showNotification(msg); if do not want to pass component

Answer (score 0):

```
<window id="win" visible="false">

</window>
```

when u need your window to be visible just do:

win.doModal();